# Improve performance of elasticsearch signals

Tags: python, performance, amazon-web-services, filter, rank

I am using system called commonsearch. Particularly for this post, we will be talking about backend part of it, witch is written in python.

The backend system streams warc file and indexe's its content to 2 elasticsearch clusters - 1) Text elasticsearch cluster 2) Document elasticsearch cluster.

The average speed of indexing, before adding my changes, was ~ 0.02 per index.

After my changes it's ~ 1.00( on aws its 0.4 ).

## **So what i did.**

I strip html for each of the warc body's using [html2text](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html2text), but it doesn't really take much time( maybe +0.02 ), but it definitely makes the performance more spiky, more content, more time needed to strip the html.

I added 2 [textblob](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/) text classifiers(naiveBays) checks for each indexed value, its training is serialized(pickle) and loaded before the loop.

The first training contains 33'000 test data, the second contains few hundred( i will be added even more to second ).

## **Performance analyze**

10 examples of each.

Before my changes:

```
Indexing http://2sao.vn/p1004c1007n20110413113841718/mau-vay-du-tiec-cho-quy-co-hoan-hao.vnn                                                                                           [64/1817]
--- 0.0224668979645 seconds ---
Indexing http://2sidesoftheocean.blogspot.com/2012/04/my-first-family-in-1940-us-census_02.html
--- 0.0367019176483 seconds ---
Indexing http://3.pulsitemeter.com/exbii/exbii-photos-aunties-bath-.html
--- 0.00342702865601 seconds ---
Indexing http://303cycling.com/Meredith-Miller-USGP-Cyclocross-Video-Specialized-bikes
--- 0.0187289714813 seconds ---
Indexing http://303magazine.com/2012/10/undead-mans-party-casselmans-hosts-zombie-crawl-aftermath-featuring-celldweller/
--- 0.0460560321808 seconds ---
Indexing http://38-avg.blogspot.com/2008/05/birdheart.html
--- 0.0178949832916 seconds ---
Indexing http://3docean.net/item/motorola-droid-razr-low-poly-/3712487?sso
--- 0.0468878746033 seconds ---
Indexing http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_hZs38tqNXns/StdbQyR_zGI/AAAAAAAAEyw/VvNCalngDbY/s1600-h/Vanderwood
--- 0.00142908096313 seconds ---
Indexing http://411mania.com/sports/young-firpo-the-best-light-heavywieght-to-never-win-a-title/
--- 0.0295450687408 seconds ---
```

After adding html2text:

```
Indexing http://17hmr.net/index.php?action=profile;area=showposts;u=994
--- 0.0240960121155 seconds ---
Indexing http://17hmr.net/index.php?board=1.3060;sort=last_post
--- 0.0262401103973 seconds ---
Indexing http://17hmr.net/index.php?topic=12827.msg177073
--- 0.0259499549866 seconds ---
Indexing http://17hmr.net/index.php?topic=6751.45
--- 0.0249440670013 seconds ---
Indexing http://1889.ca/2012/11/interview-with-horror-author-mike-kearby/
--- 0.0152020454407 seconds ---
Indexing http://1980s.fm/modules.php?name=Forums&file=profile&mode=viewprofile&u=94
--- 0.151058912277 seconds ---
Indexing http://1n73r.net/category/microsoft/windows-microsoft/xp/
--- 0.0693669319153 seconds ---
Indexing http://2013missworld.com/
--- 0.0448951721191 seconds ---
Indexing http://24demayito.blogspot.com/
--- 0.111493110657 seconds ---
Indexing http://24kadra.com/2009/03/04/serial-bratany/
--- 0.145864963531 seconds ---
```

After adding html2text and one classifier( the small one ):

```
Indexing http://102theriver.iheart.com/articles
--- 0.333050012589 seconds ---
Indexing http://1035kissfm.iheart.com/articles/trending-104650/reading-rainbow-campaign-nets-1-million-12410738
--- 0.334407091141 seconds ---
Indexing http://1037theq.iheart.com/articles/trending-465498/tiesto-celebrates-a-town-called-paradise-12478486/
--- 0.34556388855 seconds ---
Indexing http://1065ctq.iheart.com/articles/national-news-104668/new-electronic-license-plates-could-be-11383289/
--- 0.330471038818 seconds ---
Indexing http://10kbullets.com/reviews/neon-nights/
--- 0.328196048737 seconds ---
Indexing http://12160.info/group/gunsandtactics/forum/topic/show?id=2649739%3ATopic%3A1105218&xg_source=msg
--- 0.353976011276 seconds ---
Indexing http://12under12under2012.blogspot.com/2012/04/aprils-forsta-vinnare-blev.html
--- 0.363568067551 seconds ---
Indexing http://1350kman.com/settlement-reached-in-salina-contamination-cleanup/
--- 0.367321968079 seconds ---
Indexing http://14ers.com/php14ers/loginviaforum.php?prgm=peakstatus_main
--- 0.309129953384 seconds ---
Indexing http://16sarkisozleri.blogspot.com/2012/12/nasip-degilmis-demet-akaln-ftozcan-deniz.html
--- 0.361335992813 seconds ---
```

After adding html2text and one classifier( the big one ):

```
Indexing http://10000birds.com/white-crested-laughingthrush.htm
--- 2.16983008385 seconds ---
Indexing http://1012lounge.com/
--- 1.48357391357 seconds ---
Indexing http://1015store.com/dresses-by-colors/coral-dresses.html
--- 1.85999703407 seconds ---
Indexing http://1019ampradio.cbslocal.com/tag/happy-holidays/
--- 1.24361300468 seconds ---
Indexing http://102theriver.iheart.com/articles
--- 1.25308895111 seconds ---
Indexing http://1035kissfm.iheart.com/articles/trending-104650/reading-rainbow-campaign-nets-1-million-12410738
--- 1.19226098061 seconds ---
Indexing http://1037theq.iheart.com/articles/trending-465498/tiesto-celebrates-a-town-called-paradise-12478486/
--- 1.14514183998 seconds ---
Indexing http://1065ctq.iheart.com/articles/national-news-104668/new-electronic-license-plates-could-be-11383289/
--- 1.09987902641 seconds ---
Indexing http://10kbullets.com/reviews/neon-nights/
--- 1.07253599167 seconds ---
Indexing http://12160.info/group/gunsandtactics/forum/topic/show?id=2649739%3ATopic%3A1105218&xg_source=msg
--- 1.1537129879 seconds ---
```

After adding html2text and both classifiers:

```
Indexing http://12under12under2012.blogspot.com/2012/04/aprils-forsta-vinnare-blev.html
--- 1.43961000443 seconds ---
Indexing http://1350kman.com/settlement-reached-in-salina-contamination-cleanup/
--- 1.37341785431 seconds ---
Indexing http://14ers.com/php14ers/loginviaforum.php?prgm=peakstatus_main
--- 1.26939201355 seconds ---
Indexing http://16sarkisozleri.blogspot.com/2012/12/nasip-degilmis-demet-akaln-ftozcan-deniz.html
--- 1.36402606964 seconds ---
Indexing http://17hmr.net/index.php?action=profile;area=showposts;u=994
--- 1.23323822021 seconds ---
Indexing http://17hmr.net/index.php?board=1.3060;sort=last_post
--- 1.22554993629 seconds ---
Indexing http://17hmr.net/index.php?topic=12827.msg177073
--- 1.23036003113 seconds ---
Indexing http://17hmr.net/index.php?topic=6751.45
--- 1.20131611824 seconds ---
Indexing http://1889.ca/2012/11/interview-with-horror-author-mike-kearby/
--- 1.1732749939 seconds ---
Indexing http://1980s.fm/modules.php?name=Forums&file=profile&mode=viewprofile&u=94
--- 1.36015105247 seconds ---
Indexing http://1n73r.net/category/microsoft/windows-microsoft/xp/
--- 1.2988049984 seconds ---
```

## **Few mentions**

This project is also deployed on aws. When i run it on aws, its shows 0.4 per index( on my own its 1.3 ).

## **Questions**

How could i boost the performance of all of this ?
Should i make the training of my classifiers lighter, but more precise ?
Why is the difference so big between aws and my computer ?
Do you need code to understand ? I can add if needed.

All ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each question:

**How could i boost the performance of all of this ?**
Several ways are here, try Feature Selection for your text and classes, based on model you use for training(e.g Bag Of Words) or try LSA and LSI, look at this: [Text classification performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969425/text-classification-performance/38040580#38040580)

**Should i make the training of my classifiers lighter, but more precise?** based on what you mean by precise,almost yes, some model of text representation, is high dimensional and Curse Of Dimensionality might be occurred, you can use feature selection. also you can use some sampling methods to reduce training tuples of your data, look at this:
http://searchbusinessanalytics.techtarget.com/definition/data-sampling

**Why is the difference so big between aws and my computer?** that's simple, AWS has more advanced algorithm and powerful resources

Comment: Also, pyhon was at foult, as it utilized only 1 core( on 100% ). Implementing multi threading.

Comment: @IvRRimUm, python and scikit use multi process wherever it can(as best of my knowledge), for example in some classifiers you can use n_jobs=? to determine how many processor it allow to use

Comment: Thanks! Will try that